# Adding files to an MSI, from the command line?

Tags: linux, windows-installer, wine

I would like to add a custom config file for users downloading my MSI installer file. To do this I need to add a file to the pre-built MSI file just before download.

Is there a command line way to do this? (bonus points if it works under Linux or Wine)

Answer (score 0):

There is a command-line program called [`msidb.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370083%28VS.85%29.aspx), which is included in the [Windows Installer SDK](http://www.contactez.net/support/msi5.html) and can help you add files to the MSI. However, just putting the file in there isn't enough; you need to update the the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368596%28VS.85%29.aspx), [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007%28VS.85%29.aspx) tables to include the file in the installation, which means you need to have a pretty good understanding of how those pieces work and the tools to use them.

Comment: Could you please describe your answer in more detail?